# use drupal_add_js after external js scripts have already been loaded

Tags: theming, javascript

I have a simple function to call on a specific page template.
I'm calling it using this

```
<?php
    drupal_add_js("
        jQuery('.row).equalize();
    ","inline");
?>
```

and it's using an included js library called equalize.js. Which is included like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mysiteurl/js/equalize.min.js"></script>
```

I receive 'jQuery(...).equalize is not a function'. but I'm assuming that's because

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mysiteurl/js/equalize.min.js"></script>
```

is being called *after* my inline js. This only needs to be called on one page. Is there a way to force it to run after the external js file is loaded? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Note: When I run the inline js after the page is loaded in the console in the inspector it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by encapsulating the inline js in a jQuery(document).ready function. Like so

```
<?php
drupal_add_js("
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.row').equalize();
    });
", "inline");
?>
```